# ClamAV findings under Debian 9: LibreOfficeMacros and PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_0110-1 - false positives?

Tags: antimalware, debian

I'm running a recently installed Debian 9.1 with KDE and a ClamAV scan gives me these findings:

```
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/extensions/wiki-publisher/WikiEditor/Module1.xba      PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Template/ModuleAgenda.xba                       PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Tools/Listbox.xba                               PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/ImportWizard/Main.xba                           PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/ImportWizard/Language.xba                       PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/ImportWizard/API.xba                            PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/ImportWizard/FilesModul.xba                     PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/ImportWizard/DialogModul.xba                    PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/FormWizard/Language.xba                         PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/FormWizard/FormWizard.xba                       PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/FormWizard/tools.xba                            PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/FormWizard/develop.xba                          PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Template/Autotext.xba                           PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/FormWizard/Layouter.xba                         PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/FormWizard/DBMeta.xba                           PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Euro/ConvertRun.xba                             PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Euro/Protect.xba                                PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Euro/Init.xba                                   PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Euro/Common.xba                                 PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Euro/Hard.xba                                   PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Euro/Soft.xba                                   PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Euro/Writer.xba                                 PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Euro/AutoPilotRun.xba                           PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Template/Samples.xba                            PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_zh.xba                               PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_tw.xba                               PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_ja.xba                               PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_en.xba                               PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_ko.xba                               PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Internet.xba                              PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_de.xba                               PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_it.xba                               PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Currency.xba                              PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/CommonLang.xba                            PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Template/Correspondence.xba                     PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/tools.xba                                 PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_es.xba                               PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_sv.xba                               PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_fr.xba                               PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Depot.xba                                 PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Tutorials/RoadMap.xba                           PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Tutorials/TutorialClose.xba                     PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Tutorials/TutorialCreator.xba                   PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Tutorials/ShowInfoDialog.xba                    PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Tutorials/TutorialOpen.xba                      PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Tools/ModuleControls.xba                        PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Tutorials/Functions.xba                         PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Gimmicks/AutoText.xba                           PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Gimmicks/ReadDir.xba                            PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Gimmicks/GetTexts.xba                           PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Gimmicks/ChangeAllChars.xba                     PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Gimmicks/Userfields.xba                         PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Trace.xba                           PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Recordset.xba                       PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Field.xba                           PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/L10N.xba                            PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Tools/Debug.xba                                 PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Database.xba                        PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Application.xba                     PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Utils.xba                           PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/_License.xba                        PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Form.xba                            PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/OptionGroup.xba                     PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/CommandBar.xba                      PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/PropertiesSet.xba                   PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Event.xba                           PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/CommandBarControl.xba               PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Tools/Strings.xba                               PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/DataDef.xba                         PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Control.xba                         PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/acConstants.xba                     PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/TempVar.xba                         PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Root_.xba                           PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/UtilProperty.xba                    PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/PropertiesGet.xba                   PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Test.xba                            PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/SubForm.xba                         PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/DoCmd.xba                           PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Tools/UCB.xba                                   PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Compatible.xba                      PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Property.xba                        PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Collect.xba                         PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Dialog.xba                          PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Methods.xba                         PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/presets/basic/Standard/Module1.xba                          PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2     
/usr/share/mime/mime.cache                                                       PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_0110-1     
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/Tools/Misc.xba                                  PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
```

Are these are all false positives? How to best check whether they are? Are other people also getting these findings? Should I simply remove them or are those files needed or useful?

I did not install any libreoffice extensions myself. It seems they were installed at the initial installation.

[Somebody asked about PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_0110-1 earlier.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611291/clamav-pua-win-exploit-cve-2012-0110-found-usr-share-mime-mime-cache) Is it enough to run `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime/` to fix it?
I did that and it returned `Unknown media type in type 'all/all'` `Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'` and after another scan it showed the same finding again.

<sup>I'm still new to GNU/Linux and I'm not sure whether this question would be more appropriate here or at the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting exactly the same thing on Ubuntu. They appear to be a group of included macros, including tutorials. If anything, quarantine, and make sure LibreOffice work.

If you need to use the macros later or if your libre stops working, you can restore the files.